# Adding a (discard) button to the left of your Toolbar title

Tags: android, android-studio, android-toolbar, android-appbarlayout

Take a look at Google's [design guidelines](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/dialogs.html#dialogs-full-screen-dialogs). They show what seems to be a `Toolbar` with a leftmost discard button. This is exactly what I am going for.

I attempted to use a full-screen `DialogFragment`, but it did not suit the needs or structure of my app, nor was it a simple task to implement a proper `Toolbar`. I wouldn't be surprised if Google's calendar app doesn't even use a `DialogFragment` in this scenario. Speaking of that, I tried searching for sample code for the calendar app, but found none. If anyone can link some I would greatly appreciate it!!

I am now using an activity and tried using the `menu` `item` attribute `android:orderInCategory` but it did not allow me to place an item before the title. I also considered enabling the up button, but it is not ideal for this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using an `Activity`, you can do something like this in your `onCreate()`.

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.abc_ic_clear_mtrl_alpha);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

And when the option is clicked, the control will come in the `onOptionsItemSelected()`, where you can handle it as follows

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```